# Redshift prevents manual backlight adjustment (LXQt)

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, backlight, lxqt, redshift

Redshift seems to work fine, dimming my screen with the red tint at night, but when Redshift is running (whether actively enabled or not) I cannot control laptop brightness with the laptop brightness keys (F2 and F3). Instead, pressing the keys will momentarily seem to remove the Redshift effect and adjust brightness, until Redshift become active again seconds later, resetting brightness to whatever it was set to before Redshift became active.

If I quit Redshift entirely, brightness control works fine.

Using Lubuntu (LXQt) 20.04, HP Pavilion.